# Using multiple font sizes in Title of Panorama in Windows phone 8 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have added one panorama. The Title is "**World Map**", and I'd like to set the font size of "**World**" to 25 and font size of "**Map**" to 17. Is this possible, and if so how can it be done?

```
 <phone:Panorama x:Name="panoramaMain" Title="World Map" SelectionChanged="panoramaMain_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="1">

 <phone:PanoramaItem`1>
   <phone:PanoramaItem`2>
 </phone:Panorama>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Title templet like this

```
<phone:Panorama x:Name="panoramaMain" Title="World Map" SelectionChanged="panoramaMain_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="1">
            <phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>                                                                  
                        <TextBlock>
                            <Run Text="World " FontSize="25"/>
                            <Run Text="Map" FontSize="17"/>
                        </TextBlock>              
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
 </phone:Panorama>
```